# how can I write multi parameters in my url?

Tags: .htaccess, url

how can I write multi parameters in my url?
I don't want to write all parameters in on RewriteRule which is complex and not easy to match all my urls in my site , I want to write one line for one parameters each, but it is no working.

```
http://www.laji.com/p/hello-p-1002.html
(http://www.laji.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=1002)
RewriteRule ^(.*)-p-(\d+).html$ index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=$2 [QSA,L]

http://www.laji.com/fr/p/hello-p-1002.html
(http://www.laji.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=1002&language=fr)
RewriteRule ^/([\w]{2})(.*)$ $2?language=$1 [QSA,L]

http://www.laji.com/fr/c/shoe-c10/
(http://www.laji.com/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=10&language=fr)
RewriteRule ^(.*)-c(\d+)(.*)$ index.php?main_page=index&cPath=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
# http://www.laji.com/p/hello-p-1002.html
RewriteRule ^p/(.*)-p-([0-9]+)\.html$ /index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=$2 [QSA,L]

# http://www.laji.com/fr/p/hello-p-1002.html
RewriteRule ^(\w{2})/p/(.*)-p-([0-9]+)\.html$ /index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=$3&language=$1 [QSA,L]

# http://www.laji.com/fr/c/shoe-c10/
RewriteRule ^(\w{2})/c/(.*)-c([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?main_page=index&cPath=$3&language=$1 [QSA,L]
```

You want to omit the leading slash from your regex because that's removed from URI's when applying rules from an htaccess file.